# Database design for versioned database records, many views and few updates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit to clear up some confusion: I'm primarily looking to make sure select queries are fast without going into bad practice if having an `isLatest` field is considered bad practice when that information can be derived from other stored data.

I have a situation where an admin creates a "blueprint", and users work with "instances" of that blueprint but cannot modify any of data set by the admin. In general, there will be many select queries and very few create/update queries for the blueprint. Here is my current design:

```
Table BluePrintFromAdmin
    Long id //PK
    String someData
    String moreData
    ...

Table InstanceForUser
    Long id //PK
    Long bluePrintFromAdmin //FK referencing BluePrintFromAdmin id.
    String userData
    ...
```

What I need to do, though, is enable the admin to update the blueprint without affecting current instances that a user is working with. Older instances must continue to work as expected, so it doesn't make sense to create a separate table for historical blueprints. I'm considering the following:

```
Table BluePrintFromAdmin
    Long id //PK
    Date dateCreated //Datetime when this blueprint was created.
    Boolean isLatest //True if this is the most recent blueprint, false otherwise.
    String blueprintGuid //This value is the same for a blueprint and its modified blueprint, to track changed blueprints.

    String someData
    String moreData
    ...

Table InstanceForUser
    Long id //PK
    Long bluePrintFromAdmin //FK referencing BluePrintFromAdmin id.
    String userData
    ...
```

I frequently need to list all the latest blueprints and instances in a pageable manner.

My main concern is saving `isLatest` when the latest record can be derived from dateCreated and blueprint Guid. Having a separate `isLatest` would make select queries faster, since otherwise the database would need to a MAX() for each unique blueprintGuid. I'm not sure if indexing will blueprintGuid and dateCreated will enable a similar speed or will still be much slower than simply using that extra `isLatest` column.

A concrete example use case would be: A system for enabling admins to create email templates and for users to select email templates with their additions (stored separately). I need to be able to list the latest email templates for the admins, and I need users to be able to list and update their "instances". An admin could also update an email template, and both the old and new versions should work as expected.

I'm using SQL Server. Any suggestions for the database design for this use case?

Comment: What are you expecting as an answer? This is so vague and open ended.

Comment: Corrections to the database design if this isn't a good design for this use case.

Comment: Specifically with regard to "isLatest". It seems like an odd way to track changes if I also have dateCreated and can get the latest record from that, but it may be slow when it's select-heavy.

Comment: Your use case isn't at all clear. At best we could maybe guess at what you might want to be doing. But there just isn't anywhere near enough detail about your tables or the the process. And how could we offer any suggestions about improving a design we can't see?

Comment: I'll edit the question to add some more details on queries involved.

Comment: OK, I edited the question with a concrete example for this use case.

Comment: Again...where is your table definition? https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx

Comment: I'm confused - I provided pseudocode. Do you want SQL code specifically? Or are you looking specifically for code for the concrete example instead of the abstraction?

Comment: What psuedocode? There is nothing but extremely vague table definitions. And why pseudocode in the first place? You said you want to know if you should change your table design. Maybe you should include UserID in your table so you know which admin the data "belongs" to? Not trying to be snarky here but seriously. Read this and ask yourself if you would have any idea what you are asking.

Comment: Apologies, I'm used to using an ORM. I'll edit it to be a bit closer to native.

Comment: I've edited Ids. There is other data such as you mentioned, but it's not relevant to what I'm asking. I'm mostly interested in making sure the select queries are fast since the majority of queries will be select queries, but I don't want to use a bad practice if having an "isLatest" boolean is considered bad practice.

Comment: I put a notice at the top to clarify this concern as the primary concern.

Comment: The only answer here is "it depends". The actual table definition, indexing, row counts, query composition etc...I would say it seems like a bad design but there are times that kind of thing makes sense too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, it boils down to "should I denormalize by adding a column".

In cases like this, it's all about context and trade-offs. You worry about the performance of including a "MAX" clause; in practice, on modern hardware, I doubt you'll be able to tell the difference unless you're dealing with *huge* data sets - and hundreds of millions of rows is not huge. There are always weird gotchas, but if you're concerned about performance, build a test rig, fill it with 3 times the amount of data you think your system will need to handle, and optimize the schema so it handles the load you think you'll get.

If you can *prove* you have a performance problem, buy more/better hardware. It's much cheaper than the time it takes to debug problems introduced by breaking "Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)".

Only once you have a test rig, can prove you have a performance problem, and have spent money on hardware would I look at denormalization.

Why? Because it leads to bugs. And in your case, I doubt the boolean flag will have a huge effect on performance, because indexes tend to favour columns with high cardinality. Also, once you've found all the records matching a particular `ID`, the number of versions is unlikely to be huge.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I want to wait for more answers, but barring that, this will be accepted.